# Visual studio android emulator failed to launch

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

**Always getting the following issue when trying to launch the android emulator for visual studio 2015. Anyone that knows a workaround for this?**

```
0> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.0.60106.1
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.0.60106.1
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14342.0 Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: msft   - 0
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: 036046254953
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: surface pro 4
1> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 540, Version: 20.19.15.4409
2> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 3
2> 5/26/2016 1:25:25 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2> 5/26/2016 1:25:26 PM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5
3> 5/26/2016 1:25:30 PM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
3> 5/26/2016 1:25:30 PM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5.5" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XXHDPI Phone
3> 5/26/2016 1:25:30 PM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
3> 5/26/2016 1:25:30 PM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
3> 5/26/2016 1:25:30 PM : [Informational] Preparing virtual machine...
3> 5/26/2016 1:25:30 PM : [Critical] An error occurred that prevented the operation from completing successfully.
```